# Adding 'tap zones' to Synaptics touch pad?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

In Windows I can configure the corners of my touchpad to act as another button or control. For example, I use the top left as a "middle click" and the bottom left as "mute".

I have searched around and unable to find out if this is possible on Ubuntu 11.10.

My touchpad is recognised as a touchpad because I can configure the settings separately from the mouse settings.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of corners of the touchpad to certain mouse button in synclient plus the use of easystroke to link the additional mousebutton to actions allows you to achieve exactly what you are looking for. See the link to get detailled instruction. Easystroke can be found in the software center.

[how to add functions to your touch pad](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859936)